# Automatic invoice generate when order grand total is zero in magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, invoice

How do I stop auto invoice create when order grand total is zero?

In back-end payment methods zero subtotal auto invoice is set to No.

How do I stop the invoice from generating?

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is a late response but I came across this when searching for a similar issue.

Have you checked the `Current Configuration Scope`?

If you have changed `Automatically Invoice All Items` to `No` under `Zero Subtotal Checkout`, i would suggest changing this scope to the `website` or `store view` and checking these options again. It may be that the `Use Default` checkbox is deselected and the value for this option is set to `Yes`.